# Newton Polytope of a symmetric polynomial with few vertices

Tags: polygons, symmetric-polynomials, convex-geometry, sparsity

For an $n$-variate polynomial $f = \sum_{a_1,\dotsc,a_n} x_1^{a_1}x_2^{a_2} \cdots x_n^{a_n}$, its Newton polytope $P_f$ is defined as the convex hull of all exponent vectors in the support of $f$. There are known examples where number of vertices of $P_f$ is low, while total number of monomials in $f$ is high. For example in Claim 4.4 of this [paper](https://808e705d-a-62cb3a1a-s-sites.googlegroups.com/site/ilyavv/publications/Deterministic%20Factorization%20of%20Sparse%20Polynomials%20with%20Bounded%20Individual%20Degree.pdf?attachauth=ANoY7cqPPSoHiN6A9LHwCoOhlchL5WtFBtDIyvuHFfeRVjvs_LQICzMno5Bq26DFiME5WTI6wu5OzG8QGr2VN07xE5yYlTAiXadIcQf4JFlgquhcKuzjRiKSwfSB-Fph3UIny8ZmHvQBMhY7ytf64012-QWHnksoeXY3ULOQQT88DE6MouRjUn3S9Slp9Mhie3Pf8GVJk5jQtaEaIh6dHxTbL3q5tW8i5ACgqZnpW-CrbNcsCUQLsxSEgH1MN78Bj8BVq9cmxvctzQSYCeFqRobQ66bVuSagdErImi0GG1gOrV6KF9f195mLqo7wWHREABRESvabf3eh&attredirects=0), $|V(P_f)| = n$, while number of monomials are $n^{\Omega(\log n)}$. However, the example mentioned in this paper is not a symmetric polynomial. I wonder whether one can similarly find a symmetric polynomial with few vertices in its Newton polytope. More precisely,

Does there exist a symmetric polynomial $g$ with few vertices, say $|V(P_g)| = s$, while number of monomials in $g$ is at least $s^{\Omega(\log n)}$?